# Is it an identity in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

I vageuly remember having seen something like $$ \oint_C \frac{P'(z)}{P(z)} dz=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \log \left( |P(re^{i\theta})| \right) d\theta.$$ where $C$ is circle of radius $r$ centered at origin and $P(z)$ is a polynomial of degree $n.$ Is it true or my memory is failing me ?Thank you for nay help/hints

Comment: Can you atleast try and check for $P(z)=z$ and $r=1$? Is $2\pi i= 0$ ?

Comment: thank you for a simple sanity check